# phpseclib not connecting server with port

Tags: php, ssh, centos, phpseclib

I am using phpseclib library version 2. I am trying to connect a server which has port. But its not working and showing following error when trying with port

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: User Notice
>
> Message: Connection closed by server
>
> Filename: Net/SSH2.php
>
> Line Number: 1196

My code

```
include '../vendor/autoload.php';
define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', phpseclib\Net\SSH2::LOG_COMPLEX);
$port = empty($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) ? '' : ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
$server = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

$ssh = new \phpseclib\Net\SSH2($server.$port);
if (!$ssh->login('root', STMPS)) {
    //echo $ssh->getLog();return;
     print_r($ssh->getErrors());
     return;
 }
```

And when trying without port then big logs coming. Not understanding whats going wrong

Comment: Do you really intend to use the `$_SERVER` array that's [built into PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for this?

Comment: `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']` is probably not what you want, because if you access this page though a URL you'll be on PORT 80 and if you want sFTP you generally want PORT 22

Comment: My Password was wrong. in fact http port was not an issue as already it is SSH login. Problem solved.thanks